# auto rotating landscape to portrait in Ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I 'm working on an app in which I capture a picture, save it than display.
But when I take picture in Landscape it automatically rotate it and convert to portrait.

Here is My code
ImageCapture.html

```
<ion-content ng-controller="ExampleController" padding="true">
  <button class="button button-full button-assertive" ng-click="photoSave()">
    Take Photo
  </button>
  <img ng-show="imgURI !== undefined" ng-src="{{imgURI}}" style="text-align: center">
</ion-content>
```

and my controllers.js

```
.controller("ExampleController", function ($scope, $cordovaCamera) {

      $scope.photoSave = function() {
            if (window.cordova) {
              var options = { limit: 1 };
              var options = {
                quality : 75,
                destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                targetWidth: 320,
                targetHeight: 480,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: true
              };
            $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imagePath) {
              $scope.imgURI = imagePath;
              //Grab the file name of the photo in the temporary directory
              var currentName = imagePath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
              //Create a new name for the photo
              var d = new Date(),
              n = d.getTime(),
              newFileName = n + ".jpg";
              //Move the file to permanent storage
              $cordovaFile.moveFile(cordova.file.tempDirectory, currentName, cordova.file.dataDirectory, newFileName).then(function(success) {
              //success.nativeURL will contain the path to the photo in permanent storage, do whatever you wish with it, e.g:
              //createPhoto(success.nativeURL);
              alert("URI:")
              $scope.imgURI =success.nativeURL;

                }, function(error) {
                  //an error occured
                  alert("Error:"+error)
                });

                }, function(error) {
                //An error occured
                alert("Error1:"+error)
                });
              }
            };
     })
```

Why is this happening and what I 'm suppose to do to handle it

**Edit (To elaborate):**
when I take picture by holding my mobile in horizontal direction,
it captures the picture than automatically coverts it as if it was taken by holding mobile in vertical position

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what is happening?

Comment: @JurClerkx
actually my phone's home button is out of order.
So can't take screen shot
Do you want me elaborate the scenerio